# ALV-Grid: Start transaction when clicking on value

Tags: gridview, abap, sap-gui, sap-hr

My ABAP report creates a list of locked records and presents them as an *ALV grid*. For this I use the class `cl_gui_alv_grid`. To make the processing of the reported data records more efficient, it should be possible to jump directly from the list to transaction `PA20` (infotype, start date, end date).

The list has the following structure:

- personnel number
- infotype
- start date
- end date

Is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to trigger code when the user clicks an ALV hotspot field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68456861/how-to-trigger-code-when-the-user-clicks-an-alv-hotspot-field)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this should be possible.

First you would need to implement an event handler for the event `double_click` of `cl_gui_alv_grid`. You do that by creating a local class with an event handler method:

```
CLASS lcl_alv_event_handler DEFINITION.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    CLASS-METHODS:
      on_double_click FOR EVENT double_click OF cl_gui_alv_grid
        IMPORTING e_row e_column es_row_no.
ENDCLASS.
```

Then you need to implement the method `on_double_click` to read the clicked line from your data table using the content of the parameter `e_row` and then use `CALL TRANSACTION` to start the transaction PA20. You can also perform some actions in the transaction PA20 before giving control to the user, like entering a personnel number or the time and then performing the "view" action. You do that by passing a table with batch-input actions using the addition `USING bdc_tab` to CALL TRANSACTION. More about that in [the documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_756_index_htm/7.56/en-us/abapcall_transaction.htm) which also includes [an example how to do it with a batch input table](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_756_index_htm/7.56/en-us/abencall_transaction_bdc_abexa.htm).

Then you assign that event handler after you created your ALV grid:

```
SET HANDLER lcl_alv_event_handler=>on_double_click FOR go_alv.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. In the first step I try to show the clicked cell by a message. But nothing happens.     `CLASS lcl_alv_event_handler DEFINITION.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    CLASS-METHODS:
      on_double_click FOR EVENT double_click OF cl_gui_alv_grid
        IMPORTING e_row e_column es_row_no.
    ENDCLASS.

CLASS lcl_alv_event_handler IMPLEMENTATION.

METHOD on_double_click.
    MESSAGE 'Row clicked.' & 'e_row' TYPE 'I'.
ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS. `

Comment: Event handlers don't just need to be defined, they need to be assigned to a specific instance of the class they are supposed to react to. Did you set this method as the event handler for your cl_gui_alv_grid instance using the SET HANDLER keyword?